# Error while using attempting to use replace(). Not sure if syntax is correct. Am I using it correctly, because right now my program will not run

Tags: java, replace, java.util.scanner

I'm getting this error in Eclipse while trying to make a login system with the user data in another file. The error is "The method replace(String, String) is undefined for the type Scanner". Here is my source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Login {
private Formatter x;
private Scanner y;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public void addRecord() {

    String permission;
    int confirmFailed = 0;
    int existsAlready = 0;
    int invalid = 0;
    String username = null;

    System.out.println("The following questions will be entered into the user database.");
    try {
        do {
        do {
        System.out.println("What do you want the username to be?");
        username = input.nextLine();
        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("create new account")) {
            System.out.println("That user name is invalid, please try again.");
            invalid = 1;
        }
        }   while(invalid == 1);
        y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jonat\\OneDrive\\Documents\\eclipse-workspace\\Roll Die with Login\\Users\\" + username + ".txt"));
        System.out.println("That username has already been taken. Please enter a different name.");
        existsAlready = 1;
        }while(existsAlready == 1);
        y.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Thanks. What is your first name?");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Thanks. What is your last name?");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ok " + firstName + ", what do you want your password to be?");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Your entry has been created. Have fun!");
            try {
                x = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\jonat\\OneDrive\\Documents\\eclipse-workspace\\Roll Die with Login\\Users\\" + username + ".txt");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
            x.format("Username: %s\nFirst Name: %s \nLast Name: %s \nPassword: %s \nPermissions: %s\nBalance: %s\n\n",username,firstName,lastName,password,"User", "20");
            }
        x.close();
    }
public void mainMenuLogin(){
    String loginUsername;
    int invalid = 0;
    String loginPassword;
    do {
    invalid = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Casino. Please enter your username to log in. Type 'create new account' to make a new account");
    loginUsername = input.nextLine();
    if (loginUsername.equalsIgnoreCase("create new account")) {
        addRecord();
    }
    try {
        String passwordText;
        y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jonat\\OneDrive\\Documents\\eclipse-workspace\\Roll Die with Login\\Users\\" + loginUsername + ".txt"));
        System.out.println("Username found! Please enter the password for the user: " + loginUsername);
        loginPassword = input.nextLine();
        y.nextLine();
        y.nextLine();
        y.nextLine();
        passwordText = y.nextLine();
        /*line with error*/ String password = y.replace("Password: ", "");
        System.out.println(password);
        if(password == "Password: " + loginPassword) {
            System.out.println("Access Granted");
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        String yesNo;
        invalid = 0;

        System.out.println("Username not found in the database. Would you like to create a new account?");
        yesNo = input.nextLine();
        if(yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            invalid = 0;
            addRecord();
        } else {
            if(yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.println("Then please try again.");
                invalid = 1;
            }else {
                System.out.println("You entered something invalid. Try again.");
                invalid = 1;
            }
        }
}
}while(invalid == 1);
}
}
```

I am also looking for any other tips on how to make my code more efficient, but for now, I just need this program to run. My user file is named Wyld_Python.txt. Which I know, is a generic name, but please, no hate. The text file is as follows:

```
Username: Wyld_Python
First Name: Jonathan
Last Name: M
Password: Wyld_Python123
Permissions: Admin
Balance: 20
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!
Jonathan

Comment: `replace` works on a String Object, not on a Scanner object - maybe change to `password.replace (....)`

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked!

Comment: I suggest that you close this question as it will not really be of use to anyone else